# generate series based on particular day in each month -postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have following query in postgresql for dates between 2 ranges.

```
select generate_series('2019-04-01'::timestamp, '2020-03-31', '1 month') 
         as g_date
```

I need to generate specific date in every month .i.e  15 th of every month. Following is my query to generate series

```
 DO $$
    DECLARE

    compdate date = '2019-04-15';
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table ON COMMIT DROP AS
      select  *,
                   case
                        when extract('day' from d)  <> extract('day' from compdate)  then 0 
                        when ( extract('month' from d)::int  - extract('month' from compdate)::int ) % 1 = 0 then 1
                        else 0 
                        end as c
          from   generate_series('2019-04-01'::timestamp, '2020-03-31', '1 day') d;

END $$;

SELECT * FROM tmp_table
where c=1;
;
```

But every thing is perfect if input date between (1..29)-04-2019 ..

```
2019-04-25
2019-05-25
2019-06-25
2019-07-25
2019-08-25
2019-09-25
2019-10-25
2019-11-25
2019-12-25
2020-01-25
2020-02-25
2020-03-25
```

but if i give compdate: 31-04-2019 or 30-04-2019 giving out put:

```
2019-05-31 
2019-07-31 
2019-08-31 
2019-10-31
2019-12-31 
2020-01-31
2020-03-31
```

Expected Output:

```
 date        flag
2019-04-01     0   ----start_date
2019-04-30     1 
2019-05-31     1
2019-06-30     1
2019-07-31     1
2019-08-31     1
2019-09-30     1
2019-10-31     1
2019-11-30     1
2019-12-31     1
2020-01-31     1
2020-02-29     1
2020-03-31     0  ---end_date
```

If matched day not found in the result  it  should take last day of that month..i.e if 31 not found in month of feb it 
  should take 29-02-2019 and also in april month instead of 31 it should take  2019-04-30.
Please  suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot accomplish what you want with generate_series. This results due to that process applying a fixed increment from the previous generated value. Your case 1 month. Now Postgres will successfully compute correct end-of-month date from 1 month to the next. So for example 1month from 31-Jan yields 28-Feb (or 29), because 31-Feb would be an invalid date, Postgres handles it. However, that same interval from 28-Feb gives the valid date 28-Mar so no end-of-month adjustment is needed. Generate_Series will return 28th of the month from then on. The same applies to 30 vs. 31 day months.  
But you can achieve what your after with a recursive CTE by employing a varying interval to the same initial start date. If the resulting date is invalid for date the necessary end-of-month adjustment will be made. The following does that:

```
create or replace function constant_monthly_date
                         ( start_date timestamp
                         , end_date   timestamp
                         ) 
  returns setof date 
  language sql strict
as $$
with recursive date_set as
     (select start_date ds, start_date sd, end_date ed, 1 cnt
      union all
      select (sd + cnt*interval '1 month')  ds, sd, ed, cnt+1 
       from date_set
      where ds<end_date
     )
select ds::date from date_set;    
$$;

-- test
select * from constant_monthly_date(date '2020-01-15', date '2020-12-15' );
select * from constant_monthly_date(date '2020-01-31', date '2020-12-31' );
```

Comment: if input is  date '2020-01-15', date '2020-12-30' , i need following records 2020-12-16  to  2020-12-30..is is possible?

Comment: Yes and not much different. Change the line "select (sd + cnt*interval '1 month')  ds, sd, ed, cnt+1 " to "      select least(sd + cnt*interval '1 month',ed ) ds, sd, ed, cnt+1"

Comment: i have changed ..but Job taking too long. Aborted. msg showing..

Comment: What do you mean Job taking too long. As a single query I just ran the revised version from (date '1900-01-15',date '2020-12-30') - yes 120 years with. Took less than 1 second. What else ig going on here.  BTW you indicated "msg showing.." but didn't show anything.

Comment: sory ..its wrking now thanks a lot..bistake   i have changed to where ds<=end_date..

Answer (score 2):

to generate the last days of the month, just generate first days & subtract a `1 day interval`

example: the following generates all last day of month in the year 2010

```
SELECT x - interval '1 day' FROM
GENERATE_SERIES('2010-02-01', '2011-01-01', interval '1 month') x
```

Comment: thanks but expected result not always month end,,it may 1 to 31st depending on month..i.e 31st not there in feb on that case only take month end otherwise same day of every month

Comment: Edited the question pls check

Comment: @Ljt, upon re-reading your question, it is not clear to me what you want. do you want an interface that accept invalid dates and generates a series with a monthly interval? How do you want to handle cases if someone enters 13 as month?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `least` function to get the least one between the computed day and end of month.

```sql
create or replace function test1(day int) returns table (t timestamptz) as $$
        select least(date_trunc('day', t) + make_interval(days => day-1), date_trunc('day', t) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day') from generate_series('2019-04-01', '2020-03-31', interval '1 month') t
$$ language sql;
```

select test1(31);